# Are ankle socks non-tziniut?

Tags: halacha, women, clothing, tznius-modesty, parts-of-the-body

Is it permissible for a woman to wear ankle socks? The issue that comes to mind is that the area between the bottom of the skirt and the top of the socks is visible and quite substantial. But if you follow the halachah strictly - if I am not mistaken - the only requirement is that the skirt be below the knees.

What exactly might be the problem? Please provide any rabbinical sources with your answers - if there are any.

Comment: Is that part of the body customarily covered where she is going to be?

Comment: @DoubleAA, so what you're trying to say is that it depends on the community?

Comment: @DoubleAA If you have an answer ("If the community...") then I encourage you to post it.